# Need help choosing backup type and options - how do the different backup strategies apply to single file?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, acronis-trueimage, backup

I want to backup my journal to my external hard drive. Because of the nature of journals, I see no reason to keep an old version. In Acronis True Image 2013 how do I set it up so it's backed up once a week?

I don't understand this difference between incremental and differential backups in this context since it's got nothing to do with a full backup. I plan on setting to validate the backup after completion, if I'm going to delete old versions of the journal then there's no point to select "validate backups once per month" since there would only ever be the once just written. Also since it's on an external hard drive I'm going to check "wait for devices to be attached" and "wait for computer to be idle". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn't need versioning, an incremental/differential backup would save time. However in this scenario, where its a file level backup, imaging software seems wasteful, you're better off with a fast file copier like teracopy, robocopy or my current favourite, bvckup 2.

Its a single file, you want to copy it, check it to make sure its copied over correctly, and thats it. Acronis is a little like trying to use a powerdrill to drive in a nail.

In this specific case, another strategy I would consider is encrypting the file and putting it on dropbox or some other sync tool. While its no longer a single system backup, you've got a lot of the implementation details taken care of for you.

Comment: I guess the one thing Acronis would do extra is remember to do it each week and automate the copying process. I have tera copy can it be automated to copy?

Comment: No, but you could trigger off a copy process with a suitable tool using windows task scheduler. bvckup2 would do this automatically on device plugin (as I said, its my current favourite).